# Can I join a server from down the road, or do I have to be in the same room?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

Can I join someone who is not in my room? On *Minecraft PE*, I can't find any option in the settings to do this.

Comment: Pretty sure that you have to be on the same network , but I'm sure someone knows better than me.

Answer (score 1):

You must be connected to the same WiFi network as the other person. So if you can connect to their network from down the road, then yes, you can.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a problem similar to the origins of your question, but nonetheless I have done a little bit of testing to achieve the answer to your question. The WiFi has to be the same. If one person is on one WiFi access point and the other is on a separate access point, both cannot join the same server. But if the person down the road is able to connect to the WiFi network that you are on, you should be able to connect to another server.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a singleplayer world, then you have to be connected to the same wifi if it is an external server, then all you need is the password

Answer (score 0):

### 2023 Answer

If you're talking about an actually hosted server, then you need the IP, which you can generally only enter on some of the versions of bedrock, not all of them (I believe on PC and maybe mobile, not on console, though there are some DNS workarounds for those).

If you're talking about joining a friend in their singleplayer world, it doesn't matter whether you're in the same room or on the other side of the world, as long as you both have internet, you are in their friends list and they have friends joining them enabled (or specifically invite you through the friends list) you can join their world.